# What’s “tabs are not allowed in f# code unless the #indent off option is used” Error?

Tags: f#

what’s “tabs are not allowed in f# code unless the #indent off option is used” Error?
I use the last version .netcore and vs 2019. I want to use the lightweight syntax

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using lightweight syntax, you must use spaces, not tabs, for indentation.

Most editors have an option (including Visual Studio, by default) will turn a tab into spaces automatically when you type. I suspect this was written in a different editor and opened in VS.

In Visual Studio 2019, if you select everything in your document, and do `Edit->Advanced->Untabify Selected Lines`, it will correct it for you, as well.